# Laravel 5 Relationship with 3 tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

Category

```
    id      |     name      
-----------------------------------
    1       |      Men >80kg   
-----------------------------------
    2       |      Women >80kg   
-----------------------------------
    3       |      Team Men >80kg   
-----------------------------------
```

Category_Tournament (List all categories available in a tournament)

```
id | category_id | tournament_id      
---------------------------
1  |    1       |       2   
---------------------------
2  |    2       |       2   
---------------------------
3  |    3       |       2   
---------------------------
4  |    4       |       2   
---------------------------
```

Category_Tournament_User (categories registered by user)

```
id |  category_tournament_id  |       user_id       
-----------------------------------------------
1  |              1           |        201 
-----------------------------------------------
2  |              3           |        202
-----------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to sync Category_Tournament_User when User select category to participate

```
$categories = $request->get('categories_to_register');
$tournament->categories_user()->sync($categories);
```

Where my relation ManyToMany is

```
class Tournament extends Model
{
...
 public function categories_user()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_tournament_user',  'user_id','category_tournament_id');
 }
}
```

It is syncing, but not well, instead of inserting user_id, it insert tournament_id, I guess it is because I call it from Tournament Model.

I tried changing the order of relations

```
user->tournament->category or
tournament->user->category
```

but when user has no registered categories,

```
 user->tournament or
 tournament->user
```

will be null, so I can't invoke ->category

How can I fix this mess???

Comment: If you're tracking categories created by users, why aren't you storing the user_id on the category table? It would be a lot easier using a belongsTo relationship in that case, no?

Comment: I'm not tracking categories created by users. I have a catalog of categories. Then, the admin tournament decide that the tournament 1 will have 10 categories, and then the user will register only for 3 of those 10